# How to repair ods files

Tags: openoffice.org

I have few ods files but all of a sudden it is not opening. When i open the file i get the following error. Please look at the below snapshot

[image]

### Error on opening the file with Archive Manager:

[image]

```
karthick@karthick:/media/Datas$ zip -FF data.ods --out repaired_file.ods
Fix archive (-FF) - salvage what can
Found end record (EOCDR) - says expect single disk archive
Scanning for entries...
copying: mimetype  (46 bytes)
copying: Configurations2/statusbar/  (0 bytes)
copying: Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml  (2 bytes)
copying: Configurations2/floater/  (0 bytes)
copying: Configurations2/popupmenu/  (0 bytes)
copying: Configurations2/progressbar/  (0 bytes)
copying: Configurations2/menubar/  (0 bytes)
copying: Configurations2/toolbar/  (0 bytes)
copying: Configurations2/images/Bitmaps/  (0 bytes)
copying: content.xml  
zip warning: no end of stream entry found: content.xml
zip warning: rewinding and scanning for later entries
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ODS files, like all Open Document file types, are just `ZIP` files. You can try to repair the file using regular tools for repairing ZIPs. For example on the command line:

```
zip --fixfix file.ods
```

Beware that you should always operate on a copy of the file. If extracting data works, you might be able to re-assemble the file as a ZIP archive and load it in OpenOffice.org.

Before trying this, you should make sure the file is actually an ODS file. If you run

```
hexdump -C file.ods | head -1
```

It should look like this

```
00000000  50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 08  00 00 a8 a3 d3 3e 85 6c  |PK...........>.l|
```

That is, it should start with `PK`.

Also perhaps you can open the file in a different version of OpenOffice.org, or using `gnumeric` or Google Docs.

Comment: I tried it, its an ODS file. But still i cant able to open the file..

Answer (score 3):

Copy the corrupt file and let OO try to repait it. What happens?

If that doesn't help, right click on the file and choose *Open with Archive Manager*. What happens?

If this gives an error, try repairing the archive:

*to check the file for errors:*

```
zip -T file.ods
```

*to try to repair the file:*

```
zip -F file.ods --out repaired_file.ods
```

*or*

```
zip -FF file.ods --out repaired_file.ods
```

Comment: See the updated question pls..

Comment: @karthick87: see the updated answer